# Delete AWS S3 Bucket with millions of objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I want to delete an s3 bucket in aws with millions of objects. Is there a quick way of doing it through AWS CLI command or a script to delete them all without going in the console and manually doing it?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I have found is to first edit the bucket's [lifecycle policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html) to expire all objects. Then wait a day or two for the lifecycle policy to have removed all the objects from the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to delete the bucket with the object. But i think that can take a lot of time if there are a lot of objects. I think there isn't a really fast way to do this.

```
aws s3 rb --force s3://your_bucket_name
```

But perhaps everyone does a better way.